# Data transforming with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, reactive-cocoa

I'm experimenting with ReactiveCocoa and trying to solve a simple problem.

I have a rest-client which fetches data in JSON like this

```
{
    "entries": [
        {
            "objectId": "123",
            "name": "EntryName"
        },
        ...
    ],
    "count": 100500
}
```

The model which describes this respond

```
@interface MYEntriesList : MYJSONSerializableModel

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSArray *entries;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSUInteger count;

@end
```

The model for an entry

```
@interface MYEntry : MYJSONSerializableModel

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *objectId;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *itemId;

@end
```

So my task is to set an `itemId` for each entry after I fetch all entries.

I use a `RACCommand` to perform a fetch request and `MYAPIClient` returns a `RACSignal` in `-fetchContent:` which sends `next:` after deserializing from JSON to `MYEntriesList` instance.

My current implementation looks like this

```
@weakify(self);

self.fetchCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithSignalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
    @strongify(self);
    return [[MYAPIClient instance] fetchContent:self.item.objectId];
}];

RAC(self, entries) = [self.fetchCommand.executionSignals flattenMap:^RACStream *(RACSignal *executionSignal) {
    return [executionSignal map:^id(MYEntriesList *list) {
        @strongify(self);
        for (MYEntry *entry in list.entries) {
            entry.itemId = self.item.objectId;
        }

        return list.entries;
    }];
}];
```

I would like to know if this implementation corresponds to the "idea" of the ReactiveCocoa and are there any other ways to implement this?

Comment: This is a really open-ended question. Can you ask something more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You could change setting the item Id's a bit more "functional" but thats up to you really. Inside your map block:

```
return [[list.entries.rac_sequence map:^id(MYEntriesList *entry) {
                                       @strongify(self);
                                       entry.itemId = self.item.objectId;
                                   }] array];
```